# Error with the date command in Bash

Tags: bash, unix

I have the below code snippet :

```
#!/bin/bash
time="date +\"%Y-%m-%d %T,%3N\""
eval echo "`\$time` check"
```

Actually this is a part of a much larger code . I want to compute the value of time as per the above command on the fly every time the script is run and print the output.

When I run the code this is the below error I get :

> date: extra operand ‘%T,%3N"’
>   Try 'date --help' for more information.
>   check

However when I try to run the command from the command line window it runs fine. The problem is the date has to be in the same format only in the output.

`$ date +"%Y-%m-%d %T,%3N"`

`2017-01-13 11:54:36,604`

Please guide me out what should be done in this case.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: get rid of the `'\'`'s and the extra quotes. `time=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T,%3N")`

Comment: don;t use `eval`, without knowing its consequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following from my comment, your problem is that you cannot assign the result of the `date` command as you have it written, you need:

```
time=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T,%3N")
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need the indirection of `eval` and backticks.  We could simply write:

```
time=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T,%3N")
```

Comment: Thank you codeforester . I tried your way as well as tried a different way with eval . Both worked :echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T,%3N") check----"         and #!/bin/bash
dt="date +\"%Y-%m-%d\""
time="date +\"%T,%3N\""
eval echo "`\$dt` `\$time` check"